# ggplot with tryCatch: want blank plot if there's an error during expression

Tags: r, ggplot2

Some data:

```
x %>% dput
structure(list(date = structure(c(18782, 18783, 18784, 18785, 
18786, 18787, 18789, 18791, 18792, 18793, 18795, 18797, 18798, 
18799, 18801, 18803, 18805, 18806), class = "Date"), `Expired Trials` = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), `Trial Sign Ups` = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `Total Site Conversions` = c(3, 
1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), `Site Conversion Rate` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Trial to Paid Conversion Rate` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Context is within a shiny app where sometimes field 'Sessions' will exist and others it won't, depending on the users selections. Rather than display the red warning message, I just want nothing or a blank plot shown instead of an error message:

```
x %>% 
     ggplot(aes(date, Sessions)) +
     geom_col(na.rm = T) +
     geom_line(aes(y = `Site Conversion Rate`), na.rm = T)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Sessions' not found
```

Tried:

```
tryCatch(expr = {x %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date, Sessions)) +
    geom_col(na.rm = T) +
    geom_line(aes(y = `Site Conversion Rate`), na.rm = T)
}, 
error = function(e) {message(''); print(e)},
finally = {ggplot() + theme_void()})
```

But, this still spits out the error, wanted/expected a blank plot instead.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using an `if/else` expression with `all` i.e. we plot only `if` all the column names specified in plot are present or else return a blank plot

```
nm1 <- c("date", "Sessions", "Site Conversion Rate")
if(!all(nm1 %in% names(x))) {
     message("Not all columns are found")
     ggplot()
    } else {x %>% 
     ggplot(aes(date, Sessions)) +
     geom_col(na.rm = TRUE) +
     geom_line(aes(y = `Site Conversion Rate`), na.rm = TRUE)}
```

---

Or another option is `possibly` with specifying `otherwise`

```
library(purrr)
f1 <- function(x) {
  p1 <- x %>% 
      ggplot(aes(date, Sessions)) +
      geom_col(na.rm = TRUE) +
      geom_line(aes(y = `Site Conversion Rate`), na.rm = TRUE)
  print(p1)
 
 }
f1p <- possibly(f1, otherwise = ggplot())
```

-testing

```
f1p(x)
```

-output

[image]

---

Or a modification of the OP's `tryCatch`

```
tryCatch(expr = {print(x %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date, Sessions)) +
    geom_col(na.rm = T) +
    geom_line(aes(y = `Site Conversion Rate`), na.rm = TRUE))
}, 
error = function(e) {message(''); print(e)},
finally = {
       ggplot() + 
          theme_void()
})
<simpleError in FUN(X[[i]], ...): object 'Sessions' not found>
```

Comment: In your `possibly()` suggestion you have `function(x)`. `x` is also coincidentally the name of my df in this case. I was trying to figure out how to pass a df variable using your example but failed. E.g. `f1 <- function(df) {
  df %>%... ` Then, how could I pass my actual df in `f1p <- possibly(f1, otherwise = ggplot())`?

Comment: When you created the function with actual data name df, have you tried `f1p()`

Comment: I don't follow. Actually the df I'll be using is called `pdata` and it's reactive `pdata()`. I can't see how to pass it in to possibly :/

Comment: I tried e.g. `f1 <- function() {pdata() %>%...` and this runs but always shows the null plot, even when it should exist. I guess there's a flaw in how I try to pass pdata() into possibly

Comment: @DougFir I updated the post.  The issue was slightly different as the error occured in `print.ggplot` while we were trying to catch the error in ggplot, thus the catch didn't occur properly

Comment: @DougFir Now, you can call `f1p(pdata())`

Comment: @DougFir can you test now

Comment: I'm getting `Can't convert a gg/ggplot object to function`. Here's what I have: `f1 <- function(x) {pt <- x %>% ... <stuff>; print(pt)}`. This is with possibly() and then `output$channel_plot <- renderPlot(possibly(f1(pdata()), otherwise = ggplot()))`

Comment: `pdata()` is a reactive data frame

Comment: @DougFir If you check my code, it is `f1p <-possibly(f1, otherwise = ggplot())` and was called as `f1p(pdata())`.  If you are directly calling the function i.e. a lambda function `possibly(f1, otherwise = ggplot())(pdata())`

Comment: The first argument is only the function and the invokation of the new function should be aftewards `(pdata())`